# Is there a way to make a Implicit wait for a loading Block UI class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14lNO.png)So my company software has a UI blocker, what is this? It is a loading screen thats freeze the screen until all elements are loaded. The issue is that sometimes appears and sometimes not, and the XPath is always depending on the path. Also, the page can appear as loaded but the Block UI may appear (so technically the page can be loaded but not clickable). So the Web-driver tries to click it, clicks instead this UI blocker.

Is there a way to create a method that is this Class is displayed each time the driver should way until it's disappear on the whole project?

[loading image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROZKI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Selenium wait` until `element disappears`. So it will wait until your loader is invisible.

**UPDATE:** You can use `isDisplayed()` method to find out if loader is displayed or not.

```
if( driver.findElement(By.id("idOfLoader")).isDisplayed()){
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("idOfLoader")));
}
```

Comment: Good answer, you can add some more references... for example, OP might want to wait for `elementToBeClickable`...

Comment: How would you use it on a if? For example IF element appear use this wait - else, continue with the proccess?

Comment: @bsullit you can use isDisplayed() method as i updated in my answer, Please have a look

Comment: Yes, now it displays this error: TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to no longer be visible: By.id: mainBody (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval). I think it's waiting for it to be displayed, but as it does not appear it throws this error. Thanks for helping me by the way.

Comment: Yes you can increase the timeout exception time now, I added 10ms for it but it can vary depending on how long the loader keeps loading so you can increase it to 100 or try 20